# USBメモリにあるmecab-ipadic-neologdの利用

Tags: python, mecab

Python 3.5でMeCabを利用しようと考えております。辞書として、`mecab-ipadic-neologd`を利用したいのですが、`sudo`とPCの容量制限の関係で本体にインストールすることができないため、[こちら](http://qiita.com/mnakajima/items/2218363a5a58bc542e70)を参考に`sudo`の必要ないUSBメモリに`mecab-ipadic-neologd`を保存しています。

しかし、PythonのMeCabライブラリで使うと、`mecab = MeCab.Tagger ("mecabrc -d  /Volumes/USB/MeCab/mecab-ipadic-neologd/")`に対して、

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-95f14a0cbfb9> in <module>()
      1 sample_u = "テスト用の文章を作りました。"
----> 2 mecab = MeCab.Tagger ("mecabrc -d  /Volumes/USB/MeCab/mecab-ipadic-neologd/")
      3 print(mecab.parse(sample_u))

/home/S/.conda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MeCab.py in __init__(self, *args)
    305     if _newclass:version = staticmethod(_MeCab.Tagger_version)
    306     def __init__(self, *args):
--> 307         this = _MeCab.new_Tagger(*args)
    308         try: self.this.append(this)
    309         except: self.this = this

RuntimeError:
```

というエラーが出ます。何か解決策はありますでしょうか。ちなみに、`MeCab.Tagger ("mecabrc")`ではきちんと動きます。

Comment: `MeCab.Tagger("mecabrc -d /Volumes/USB/MeCab/mecab-ipadic-neologd/")` の部分ですが、少し調べてみた所、`MeCab.Tagger("-d /Volumes/USB/MeCab/mecab-ipadic-neologd/")` とする様です(コーパスのディレクトリのみを指定)。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます。コメントいただいたように試してみたのですが、やはり同じエラーがでます。USBに入れる際に何か問題があったのでしょうか。

Comment: コマンドラインで mecab -d /Volumes/USB/MeCab/mecab-ipadic-neologd/ して動きますか？